# GPU memory increases with each frame (leak)?

Tags: python, opengl, memory-leaks, gpu

I am rendering an image which is updated every frame by making it a texture of a square 2D plate (comprised from 2 triangles). However, GPU memory seems to increase monotonically with every frame.

### The draw function looks like this:

```
prog = gloo.Program(vertex, fragment, count=4)

def Draw(self, inImRGB):
    texture = inImRGB.copy().view(gloo.Texture2D)
    texture.interpolation = gl.GL_LINEAR
    CBackgroundImage._prog['texture'] = texture
    CBackgroundImage._prog.draw(gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)
```

### And it is called periodically, for each new available image, using the following callback:

```
from glumpy import app
window = app.Window(...)
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    bgImageObj.Draw(newImRGB)
```

Any idea why GPU memory keeps accumulating ?  Should I somehow free the texture each new frame, or fill it in a different way? If so, how?

Comment: How do you know that GPU memory is increasing?

Comment: I use the command nvidia-smi, and it displays the used GPU memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> texture = inImRGB.copy().view(gloo.Texture2D)
> ```

Creates and all new texture; eventually the Phython GC will clean up the old stuff, but that's not going to happen, if there's no shortage of memory.

Create the texture during initialization and then *reuse*.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I initialized the texture only once, using the command texture = inImRGB.copy().view(gloo.Texture2D)  and then for each new image I just assigned the image, without creating a new texture by using _prog['texture']=newImRGB and the GPU memory leakage stopped!

Comment: @roy111: You probably don't even have to do the reassignment as well. I'm not that deeply familiar with the innards of glumpy, but this looks like setting a shader program's uniform value, which is something, that doesn't spontanously change. So if you don't make a different assignment to the same program/uniform somewhere else in your code, it shouldn't change, too.

Comment: I am changing the texture every draw. I am actually using it as a screen: a 2D plate (comprised from 2 triangles) is the plate, and the texture is the video projected on that plate, so I do need to update the texture with the new video frame for each draw call.

Comment: @roy111: Then the abstractions of `glumpy` may be in your way. The contents of an OpenGL texture image can be updated, without generating a new texture object. See `glTexSubImage2D` – updating texture images through this mechanism is the preferred method for implementing video textures.